# Yodlee - how to get only new transactions

Tags: yodlee

I am looking for a way to get only 'new' transactions from specific account item. I.e. only transactions that was posted to account after I made previous transactions fetch/search.

For example I have the following scenario:

1. I have add item to consumer. Lets say consumer have 1 account item named 'BankAccount1'.
2. I fetch/search ALL transactions for some BankAccount1 and store transactions locally.
3. Now I need a way to get only new transactions on periodic basis. I.e. only transactions that was posted to 'BankAccount1' after previous fetch/search call. Is it possible to do this or I need to get all transactions every time and just skip transactions with Id which already present locally? If transaction Id is unique and incremental (did they?) maybe its possible to save last fetched transaction Id, and on next time get only transactions with Id > prevFetchId (what API to use if its possible)?

p.s.

I am using container based approach REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, I can infer that you are going to store transactions locally in your DB. In that case Yodlee recommend to use Procedural Data Extracts, using which you can keep your DB in sync with Yodlee Cloud. You can find more details about it [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Extract_Procedures).

Yodlee recommends you to pass date range in the executeUserSearchRequest API to get the transactions for any specific duration,as getting only new transactions may cause some issues. This is why Yodlee recommends to have few days of overlap, this will help you in not missing any transaction.

Transaction ID would be unique but it may not be incremental.

Comment: One issue we see with Yodlee is they will provide a transaction with a specific Yodlee transactionID on one day maybe `Debit card payment`, then the following day we poll we get another transaction with the same date and amount but a different Yodlee ID and an extended description say `Debit card payment - Tesco Stores`. The transaction ID Yodlee supply therefore is not a reliable key, so we need to perform our own dup checking.

Comment: @QFDev This seems to be an issue, unless first time when you get the transaction it is having status as pending and later it is converted to posted. I'd recommend you to speak to Yodlee support team in that case.